# Why break command didnt work in sql oracle?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I need to make a job application report, I need to produce a table where the duplicated job_id and job_name will be removed from the table
And I actually want to compute total applicants who apply for the job and then I need to get remaining job vacancies (no_of_vacancies - count(*)) and get the percentage by (count(*)/no_of_vacancies*100)

| Applicant ID | Job ID | Job Name | No of Vacancies | Remaining Job Vacancies | Percentage(%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0001 | Clinical Specialist | J0001 | 30 | 24 | 20 |
| A0072 |  |  |  |  |  |
| A0076 |  |  |  |  |  |

but I could only get this

| Applicant ID | Job ID | Job Name | No of Vacancies | Remaining Job Vacancies | Percentage(%) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0001 | Clinical Specialist | J0001 | 30 | 29 | 3 |
| A0072 | Clinical Specialist | J0001 | 30 | 29 | 3 |
| A0076 | Clinical Specialist | J0001 | 30 | 29 | 3 |

The duplicated job id and name, no of vacancies and remaining vacancies is still there, and the percentage they shown is incorrect too
Here's the code:

```
SET pagesize 30
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

ACCEPT v_jobID CHAR FORMAT 'A5' PROMPT ' Enter job id:  '

COLUMN job_id FORMAT A12 HEADING "Job ID"; 
COLUMN job_name FORMAT A20 HEADING "Job Name"; 
COLUMN applicant_id FORMAT A12 HEADING "Applicant ID"; 
COLUMN no_of_vacancies FORMAT 999 HEADING "No of Vacancies"; 
COLUMN Remaining_Job_Vacancies FORMAT 999 HEADING "Remaining Job Vacancies";
COLUMN Percentage FORMAT 999 HEADING "Percentage(%)";  

BREAK on J.job_id on job_name skip2 on no_of_vacancies, Remaining_Job_Vacancies, Percentage;
COMPUTE number LABEL 'Total Applicants' ON A.applicant_id;

TTITLE CENTER 'Job Application Report for ' _DATE -
RIGHT 'Page No: ' FORMAT 999 SQL.PNO SKIP 2

SELECT A.applicant_id, J.job_id, job_name, no_of_vacancies, (no_of_vacancies - count(*)) AS Remaining_Job_Vacancies, (count(*)/no_of_vacancies*100) AS Percentage
FROM applicant A, job J, application AP
WHERE A.applicant_id = AP.applicant_id 
AND AP.job_id = J.job_id 
AND J.job_id LIKE '&v_jobID'
GROUP BY A.applicant_id , J.job_id, job_name, no_of_vacancies
ORDER BY J.job_id;

--CLEAR COLUMNS
--TTITLE OFF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't break on `table_alias.column_name`

```
BREAK on J.job_id
         --
         ^
         |  
        this
```

but only on column name (or its alias):

```
BREAK on job_id
```

---

I don't have your tables nor data, so I'll use Scott's sample schema to illustrate it.

This is what you did:

```
SQL> break on e.deptno
SQL>
SQL> select e.deptno, e.ename from emp e order by e.deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 CLARK
        10 KING
        10 MILLER
        20 JONES
        20 FORD
        20 ADAMS
        20 SMITH
        20 SCOTT
        30 WARD
        30 TURNER
        30 ALLEN
        30 JAMES
        30 BLAKE
        30 MARTIN

14 rows selected.
```

This is what you should have done:

```
SQL> break on deptno
SQL>
SQL> select e.deptno, e.ename from emp e order by e.deptno;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 CLARK
           KING
           MILLER
        20 JONES
           FORD
           ADAMS
           SMITH
           SCOTT
        30 WARD
           TURNER
           ALLEN
        30 JAMES
           BLAKE
           MARTIN

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: hi there, just want to ask whether I can break on multiple attribute name?
BREAK on job_id on job_name on no_of_vacancies, Remaining_Job_Vacancies, Percentage

Comment: and when I want to do "COMPUTE number LABEL 'Total Applicants' ON applicant_id"
It didn't work, is it because I used it wrongly?

Comment: I have 6 rows that chose Job 1 but The remaining job vacancies only reduced by one instead of  reduced by 6, it also happened to percentage as well

Comment: You can break on multiple columns. COMPUTE "number"? What "number"? We compute SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX and stuff, not "numbers", and the syntax would be e.g. `compute sum label "Total" of sal on deptno` (i.e. you'd want to compute sum of all salaries per department.

Comment: oh I see, I actually want to get the remaining job vacancies by subtracting no_of_vacancies and count(*), the no_of_vacancies is 30 for that particular job named job A and for count(*) is basically the number of applicants applying for job A
SELECT no_of_vacancies 
  FROM applicant A, job J, application AP 
  WHERE A.applicant_id = AP.applicant_id 
  AND AP.job_id = J.job_id 
  AND AP.job_id LIKE 'J0001'
MINUS
SELECT count(*)
  FROM applicant A, job J, application AP 
  WHERE A.applicant_id = AP.applicant_id 
  AND AP.job_id = J.job_id 
  AND AP.job_id LIKE 'J0001';